# Conversion from .pdf to .odt: latin characters and accentuation problem

Tags: conversion

I'm trying to convert a pdf document created with latex to odt or doc with the tool available at [online2pdf.com](http://online2pdf.com).
My preamble is this:

```
\documentclass[article,oneside, 12pt]{abntex2} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Pacotes essenciais
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite} % Citações padrão ABNT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Pacotes auxiliares
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

All latin characters (like ç) and letters with accentuation (ã, õ, í)are rendering incorrectly like this:

[image]
[image]

I want to know if this is something related to my preamble.

Comment: it would probably work better if you added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (You should have that anyway in the latex document otherwise hyphenation will be incorrect)

Comment: you can convert your document directly to ODT using tex4ht. Try `mk4ht oolatex filename.tex` command. It correctly converts the accents with your sample file and it also supports stuff like sections and other structural commands, which conversion based on PDF probably cannot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, inserting `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` makes things worse. I get a bunch of symbols.

@michal.h21, this is a really good alternative. Have tested it before. 

What i really want to achieve is some way of checking my documents against grammatical errors. So i thought in converting do odt and checking there. The other alternative is using opendetex + languagetool as i'm doing now. It's an awesome setup, but too laborious. It would be nice to have grammatical check in directly in TexMaker. As i can see this feature doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: there is [Language Tool](https://languagetool.org/), which has support in some editors, for example Vim. I don't know about TeXMaker support. Anyway, you can simplify the conversion using the development version of [Make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht): `make4ht -um draft -f odt filename.tex`. It should be faster than `mk4ht`, because it compiles the LaTeX only once, instead of three times.